# Uncaught exception PDOException : integrity constraint violation error

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am having an error of

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gymdatabase`.`nutrition`, CONSTRAINT `nutrition_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`food_id`) REFERENCES `food` (`food_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Nutrition_model.php:11 Stack trace: #0 G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Nutrition_model.php(11): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\Nutrition.php(59): Nutrition_model->insert() #2 [internal function]: Nutrition->create() #3 G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\app\core\App.php(38): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\index.php(5): App->__construct() #5 {main} thrown in G:\5th semester\Ecommerce\xampp\htdocs\app\models\Nutrition_model.php on line 11

So there are 2 tables in my database.
In the food table there are columns food_id, name, description, path.
In the nutrition table there are columns nutri_id, user_id, food_id.
So in the nutrition table there is a foreign key which is food_id
and I don't have any data yet in both tables.
I have this error many times but it was mostly because my foreign key was restrict to delete or there are already data in the table that violates constraints but this isn't the case.

```
public function insert()//for event
    {
        $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO nutrition(user_id, food_id) VALUES(:user_id, :food_id)");
        $stmt->execute(['user_id'=>$this->user_id,'food_id'=>$this->food_id]);
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }

public function create()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['nutrition_action']))
        {       

            $nutrition = $this->model('Nutrition_model');
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $nutrition->user_id = $user_id;

            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];     
            $cheating = $_POST['cheating'];


            if($cheating == "Hell Yes")//CH
            {
                $food = 1;

            }
            else if($gender == "Male")
            {
                if($type == "Lose Weight") //ML
                {
                    $food = 4;

                }
                else if($type == "Maintain Weight") //MM
                {
                    $food = 7;
                }
                else//MG
                {
                    $food = 10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($type == "Lose Weight")
                {
                    $food = 0;
                }
                else if($type == "Maintain Weight")
                {
                    $food = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    $food = 0;
                }
            }
            $nutrition->food_id = $food;
            $nutrition->insert();

            //header('location:/Nutrition/automatic_index');//send somewhere
        }
        else
        {
            $this->view('nutrition/nutrition_create');
        }


    }
```

Comment: `I don't have any data yet in both table`... so that's the issue, right? Add some food to your `food` table so the foreign key in `nutrition` is happy.

Comment: I just put some datas in food table but still get the same error :( I mean the data that correspond the data in nutrition table

Comment: You are definately right..! I had some datas in food table but the datas didn't match with datas in nutrition table! Thank you so much! it was a silly mistake lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key constraint requires a record in the foreign table for INSERT.

A record cannot be deleted if it is still referenced from another table and has a FK constraint.

With ON DELETE CASCADE, if you delete a food record, all nutrions with this food_id will be deleted as well.